# How to prove $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{a-c}{b-d}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My question:

> How do I prove the following property of ratio?
> $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{a-c}{b-d} \tag{1}$$
> $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 0 \}$

I want to use the result in argument below.

---

> Use the sine rule to establish the following identities for triangles:
> $$\frac{a+b}{c}=\frac{\sin(A) +\sin(B)}{\sin(C)}$$ and \begin{equation}\frac{a-b}{c}=\frac{\sin(A) -\sin(B)}{\sin(C)}\end{equation}

To prove both these identities the equations rearrange to the following
$$\frac{\sin(C)}{c}=\frac{\sin(A)+\sin(B)}{a+b}=\frac{\sin(A)-\sin(B)}{a-b} $$
From here, $(1)$ would complete the argument.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your last display isn't an identity, and it isn't Number Theory; it is, as written, nonsense. I *think* what you mean to ask is, how does one prove that IF $a/b=c/d$ THEN all four of those fractions are equal. So: suppose $a/b=c/d$ Multiply both sides by $bd$ to get $ad=bc$. Add $ab$ to both sides to get $a(b+d)=b(a+c)$. Then IF WE FURTHER ASSUME $b\ne0$ and $b+d\ne0$ we can divide both sides by $b(b+d)$ to get $a/b=(a+c)/(b+d)$. Now, can you do the one with $(a-c)/(b-d)$?

Comment: That's called *"Componendo et Dividendo"*, see the proof [here](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove your requested expression (note there are limitations as [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/785985/gerry-myerson)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802366/how-to-prove-fracab-fraccd-fracacbd-fraca-cb-d/3802372#comment7836247_3802366) explains, e.g., $b \neq 0$, $d \neq 0$, $b + d \neq 0$, $b - d \neq 0$, etc.), cross-multiply and use other manipulations to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{b} & = \frac{c}{d} \\
ad & = bc \\
ad + cd & = bc + cd \\
d(a + c) & = c(b + d) \\
\frac{a + c}{b + d} & = \frac{c}{d}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You can similarly prove that $\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a - c}{b - d}$. Note, however, you can prove the $2$ requested identities more simply as shown below. The [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) gives

$$\frac{a}{\sin(A)} = \frac{b}{\sin(B)} = \frac{c}{\sin(C)} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Cross-multiplying the left & right parts gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a\sin(C) & = c\sin(A) \\
\frac{a}{c} & = \frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(C)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Similarly, using the middle & right parts in \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$\frac{b}{c} = \frac{\sin(B)}{\sin(C)} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Adding \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$\frac{a+b}{c}=\frac{\sin(A) +\sin(B)}{\sin(C)} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

while \eqref{eq3A} minus \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$\frac{a-b}{c}=\frac{\sin(A) -\sin(B)}{\sin(C)} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Answer (score 2):

But why not use this simple solution:

$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=x \implies a=bx , c = dx
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a+c}{b+d}&=\frac{bx+dx}{b+d}\\
\\
&=x\\
\\
\frac{a-c}{b-d}&=\frac{bx-dx}{b-d}\\
\\
&=x
\end{align}
$$

For the desired result, use sine rule

$$
\begin{align}
a&=2R\sin{(A)}\\
b&=2R\sin{(B)}\\
c&=2R\sin{(C)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Another excellent solution, thanks.